# How can I bind to the saved event on Mercury?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm exploring Mercury JS at the moment and can't seem to figure out a way to bind to the saved event.

According to the [API docs](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/wiki/Mercury-API), it should be as simple as:

```
Mercury.on("saved", function(event) { 
  // something here
}
```

...but that kicks up an error!

The following also doesn't work:

```
$(window).bind('mercury:saved', function() {
  // no joy here either :(
};
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting the event function inside mercury:ready event.

Try

```
jQuery(window).on('mercury:ready', function() { 
    Mercury.on('saved', function(){
       alert("It's working!");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

```
jQuery(window).bind('mercury:ready', function()
```

was working, but

```
jQuery(window).bind('mercury:saved', function()
```

wasnt.

Wired, but clearing the Browser-Cache did it for me.